# How can I make TypeScript elide star/wildcard imports that are only supposed to be used in type contexts?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using a library called turf.js.
They do not offer a specific type definition file but instead suggest to install the node module and have typescript find the types as such:

`import * as turf from '@turf/turf';`

This works nicely while editing. All types are picked up.

In the generated .js file it looks like this.

`import * as turf from '@turf/turf';`

I don't want or need that in the .js file. If I leave it in there the browser will fail to load the file with an error.  If I simply comment that line out, everything works as expected.

The turf file is getting loaded from a cdn via a normal script tag.

How do I tell VS Code / TypeScript that is just used for type hints?

I have tried finding options in tsconfig.json to exclude an import but didn't find anything.

Comment: TypeScript 5 supports `import type * from ...` syntax

Comment: @llllvvuu source on the v5 thing? I tried looking but couldn't find it, and my weak attempt to check with v4.9 didn't find any error with `import type * ...`. Also, I tried looking for a duplicate target but couldn't find one. If anyone knows of one, let me know and I can delete my answer here.

Comment: @starball you're right, i was thinking of `export type *`: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-rc/#support-for-export-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that weirds me out about what you're asking is that- to my understanding, as long as you don't touch any of the following options- [`verbatimModuleSyntax`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#verbatimModuleSyntax) (introduced in v5.0), [`preserveValueImports`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#preserveValueImports), and [`importsNotUsedAsValues`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#importsNotUsedAsValues) options- the import should be elided if you only use it in type contexts.

That aside, you should be able to write `import type * as foo from "path"`. Note that type-only imports are only supported since version 3.8 of TypeScript.

If you actually use it as a value (and not just in type contexts), but still want the import to be elided, then either tweak something with your post-processing (Ex. build system / tree shaking things), or use/abuse [triple-slash references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-path-).

Comment: This seemed like it might work. I can use the types just fine and the import isn't emitted but this makes a problem. ex.. let distance = turf.lineDistance(lineString); gives an error TS1361: 'turf' cannot be used as a value because it was imported using 'import type'.

Comment: @crashed99 I'm confused though. why then did your original title say "used only for type hints"?

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answere because it did work for types but not values.

Comment: I got values from the same library to work by adding a line `type turfType = typeof turf;` and `turf:tufType = window["turf"]`. Now I can use turf types or I can use `turf.lineDistance(lineString);` with full intellisense and no compiler error.